# Error Running NativeDriver with Maven (Software caused connection abort: recv failed)

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm trying to use Maven to run NativeDriver Android tests on a
continuous integration server (like Hudson).
I run the following commands (some names replaced with *):

(in Android project)

```
mvn install
mvn android:deploy
```

(in NativeDriver test project)

```
adb shell am instrument ***.*****.android3/
com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation
adb forward tcp:54129 tcp:54129
mvn test
```

I then get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException:Software caused connection abort: recv failed
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidNativeDriver
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:406)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:103)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:86)
    at
com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.client.AndroidNativeDriver.<init>(UnknownSource)
    [... many more]
```

In Eclipse, when i run it [following this guide](https://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/wiki/AndroidMakeAnAppTestable) on my project, everything works like a charm.

What is going on? Does Eclipse (with Android plugin) do anything special compared to maven when choosing "Run as -> Android Application"?

Comment: (Cross-posted on http://groups.google.com/group/nativedriver-users/browse_thread/thread/d65156ccaef82d8c)

Comment: I'm trying the same thing and it seems to do with bundling the standalone-server.jar (i.e. maven isn't doing it where eclipse is) with the apk still don't have an answer unfortunately